# Reducing time complexity with better approach

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a task, I have an array of numbers. The difference between two adjacent number is called as cost. Now I want to remove k consecutive array elements such that the total cost of remaining elements is minimum.

**Example:**

```
Arr = [3,7,1,11,8]
k = 2
```

**Ans:** `5`

**Explanation:**

```
Remove [3,7] so [1,11,8] then cost = |1-11| +  |11-8| = 10 + 3 = 13

Remove [7, 1] so [3,11,8] then cost = |3-11| +  |11-8| = 11

Remove [1,11] so [3,7,8] then cost = |3-7| +  |7-8| = 5

Remove [11, 8] so [3,7,1] then cost = |3-7| +  |7-1| = 10

Answer = Minimum of costs [13, 11, 5, 10] = 5.
```

**constraints:**

```
K belongs to 1 to 10^5
arr[i] belongs to 1 to 10^9
```

My code:

```
static long process(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
    int n = arr.size();
    long min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - k; i++) {
        int m = -1;
        boolean begin = false;
        long cost = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j < i || j >= i + k) {
                int p = arr.get(j);
                if (!begin) {
                    begin = true;
                } else {
                    cost += Math.abs(m - p);
                }
                m = p;
            }
        }
        min = Math.min(min, cost);
    }
    return min;
}
```

Time complexity of this code is O(n<sup>2</sup>). How to improve this code further to reduce time complexity.

Comment: Should be doable in O(n) with a sliding window.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant way to code a O(n) solution, but I think it should work. This uses a sliding window as [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) suggested.

```
public static int minCost(int[] arr, int k) {
    if (arr.length <= k + 1) {
        // In this case, we can just remove all (or all but one) element to get zero cost.
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        // currentCost is current cost savings.
        int currentCost = 0;
        int totalCost = 0;
        // Build the first window.
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i+=1) {
            currentCost += Math.abs(arr[i+1] - arr[i]);
            totalCost += Math.abs(arr[i+1] - arr[i]);
        }
        int maxCost = currentCost;
        // Account for next element in window and new cost incurred between elements on either side of the window.
        currentCost += Math.abs(arr[k+1] - arr[k]) - Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[k+1]);
        totalCost += Math.abs(arr[k+1] - arr[k]);
        if (currentCost > maxCost) {
            maxCost = currentCost;
        }
        for (int i = k + 1; i < arr.length - 1; i+=1) {
            // Current cost changes by:
            //     + Cost between new element in the new window and the element after.
            //     - New cost between elements on either side of the new window.
            //     + Cost between elements on either side of the old window.
            //     - Cost between the element leaving the window and its previous element.
            currentCost += Math.abs(arr[i+1] - arr[i]) - Math.abs(arr[i-k-1] - arr[i-k]) + Math.abs(arr[i-k-1] - arr[i]) - Math.abs(arr[i-k] - arr[i+1]);
            totalCost += Math.abs(arr[i+1] - arr[i]);
            if (currentCost > maxCost) {
                maxCost = currentCost;
            }
        }
        // Account for cost between element on either side of the old window and the cost between the element leaving the window and its previous element.
        currentCost += Math.abs(arr[arr.length-1-k-1] - arr[arr.length-1]) - Math.abs(arr[arr.length-1-k-1] - arr[arr.length-1-k]);
        if (currentCost > maxCost) {
            maxCost = currentCost;
        }
        return totalCost - maxCost;
    }
}
```

I used an `int` array to guarantee fast random access. If you know your `List` has constant access time, you could replace `arr[i]` with `arr.get(i)`. Otherwise, depending on your `List` implementation, you might instead copy your `List` into an array before running this function—you should still get a O(n) running time so long as copying takes O(n) time.